# Video, picture, or image?

Tags: word-choice, differences

How do I clearly distinguish between:

- Moving images **only**
- Moving images and audio

Using as few words as possible, without it sounding 'awkward' of course.

> **Black Hat Guy:**   "I was watching and listening to this moving image with audio data stream on my LCD screen and speakers respectively about..."
>
> **Mrs. Roberts:**      "You were *what?*"
>
> **Black Hat Guy:**   "I was watching a video on my computer about..."

For both technical and non-technical usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For both technical and non-technical usage, the clearest and most straightforward terms also happen to be the standard terms, such as in [this guideline](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv.html) from the W3C (World Wide Web Consortium):

- audio-only
- video-only
- audio-video

For example, in their [Flash Media Developer Guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7fea.html#WSDCE65C66-98CE-4a34-BB7A-AC32BAA98E33), Adobe refers to *video-only* streams, *video and audio* streams, and *audio-only* streams.

Answer (score 1):

For most audiences, *video* or *movie* would be interpreted to mean something with both pictures and sound, unless you specify otherwise. The most familiar way of saying a video of some length only has moving pictures is that it's a *silent movie*. For a short item, we might call it a *silent animation*.

Technical documents such as [this W3C guideline](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv-av-only-alt.html#key-terms) use words like *audio-only* and *video-only* but make sure to define them for readers. Here, the familiar term *silent movie* is an example of a *video-only* presentation. *Video with no audio information* is also used to make the meaning clear; in many contexts, even technical audiences may assume video can include audio unless its absence is mentioned.